# Salome issue with loading Binaries

Tags: 20.04, libraries, shared-library, binary

I've installed Salome 9.7.0 and can get it started without errors. An issue comes up when I try to use some of the binaries. Most load and work fine, but I've listed the ones with probelems below.

Geometry

Mesher

Hexablock

Homard

Hello

They all have the same message, I've attached a screenshot of an example for Geomerty and have written it as seen below.

"Can not load library libGEOM.so. libOpenGL.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I checked in the binaries file under the Solome folder and each of the problematic binaries have that file within their structure. I've compared the location of that file to that of the working binaries, and it there is no difference in their structure. This makes me think that something is wrong with the libOpenGL.so file in that it's pointing to the wrong location, but I haven't really dealt with this kind of issue before.

I look forward to seeing the suggestions, and I appreciate your help!

Thank you

[image: error_message]

Comment: Your question is not reproducible. What is your Ubuntu version? How SALOME was installed? Using which installation media?

Comment: Hi N0rbert, I followed the instructions under the "SALOME Packages" section here: https://www.salome-platform.org/downloads/current-version    I have Ubuntu 20.04, so I used the package specific to that system. I used a command on the SAT file to check if I have all the necessary packages and use synaptic to install anything I was missing. After that, I just use the "salome" command and it opens fine but throws that message box when I try to use the binaries, as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consult with README file from the distribution.

On my fresh Ubuntu 20.04 LTS VM I successfully run SALOME using below commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-system1.71.0 libqwt-qt5-6 libqt5xml5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5test5 libqt5x11extras5 libqt5help5 libfreeimage3 libtbb2 python3-sip python3-pyqt5 python-is-python3 python3-babel python3-pytest-cython python3-jinja2 python3-pygments python3-sphinx python3-alabaster cmake python3-cycler python3-docutils graphviz python3-imagesize python3-kiwisolver liblapack3 clang python3-matplotlib libmetis5 python3-numpy python3-packaging python3-pyparsing python3-tz python3-scipy python3-stemmer python3-sphinx-rtd-theme python3-sphinxcontrib.websupport sphinx-intl libtcl libtk libopengl0 libboost-all-dev libboost1.71-all-dev pyqt5-dev pyqt5-dev-tools libcppunit-dev doxygen libeigen3-dev libfreeimage-dev libfreetype6-dev libgraphviz-dev liblapack-dev libxml2-dev llvm-dev mesa-common-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libmetis-dev qttools5-dev libqt5svg5-dev libqt5x11extras5-dev qtxmlpatterns5-dev-tools libqwt-qt5-dev libscotch-dev python3-sip-dev swig libtbb-dev tcl-dev tk-dev

cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://files.salome-platform.org/Salome/Salome9.7.0/SALOME-9.7.0-native-UB20.04-SRC.tar.gz
tar -xf SALOME-9.7.0-native-UB20.04-SRC.tar.gz
cd SALOME-9.7.0-native-UB20.04-SRC
. env_launch.sh
./salome
```

Note: if you still miss dependencies use special command `./sat config SALOME-9.7.0-native --check_system` inside `SALOME-9.7.0-native-UB20.04-SRC` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the suggestions. What ended up working is I installed apt-file and searched for libOpenGL.so locations to make sure I had them. I then installed libOpenGL.0 with apt-get and everything works fine.